# Choosing FQDN for Internal Use (avoiding split DNS)

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-name

I've been looking everywhere for a definative answer to this. We are recreating our interal Windows domain and trying to come up with a FQDN for our TLD.

Currently we are using "company.co.uk" internally. We own this domain and also use it for our public website. This causes all sorts of DNS issues internally and by creating a new domain we were hoping to avoid all that micromanagment.

We want something like "company.local", however this would conflict with Bonjour.

Would using something like "local.company.co.uk" or "ad.company.co.uk" still present us with DNS issues? We want to avoid split DNS.

Thanks

Comment: Close this.  Duplicate x100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdomains are the perfect use of registered domains for internal DNS, you won't be trampling on other people's valid domains, they will not conflict with your external domains, you can keep them private or expose them to the world (I prefer to keep them private). They also require just a small change on the part of employees, instead of www.company.uk, they can use www.ad.company.uk, and so forth.

Just remember to treat them like proper domains, set up valid RDNS and so forth.